# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi.responses'

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I am trying to use `HTMLResponse` from FastAPI, as described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/). I'm on version 0.70. I keep getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi.responses'
```

My code is shown below:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
import os
from os import curdir, environ as env

app = FastAPI()

name='fred'
@app.get("/getName")
def returnName():
html_content = """
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Some HTML in here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Name is {{name}}</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=html_content, status_code=200)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError` simply means that the Python interpreter could not find the module (namely `FastAPI.responses`) on your device. Probably you just need to make sure you have it installed properly (see https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-responses/).

Comment: That pip project is unrelated to what OP wants to do. `fastapi.responses` is part of the fastapi package.

Comment: im running this is a virtualenv and have confirmed several times that the package is in fact installed. This is pretty damn frustrating.

Comment: run `pip freeze` and see your installed packages

Comment: what is your python version? run `python3 --version`

Answer (score 1):

Since FastAPI is built on top of Starlette, try this:

```
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using an older version of FastAPI.

So, you have to use:

```
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse
```

In the latest version of FastAPI 0.75.0, you can use:

```
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, JSONResponse
```